# Magento 2 controller values save via model in custom table without load model?

Tags: save, magento2.2.3

I want to call model in controller and save values via model in controller.

```
protected $pageFactory;
protected $quesModelFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \CUSTOM\Proques\Model\Ques $quesModelFactory
)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->quesModelFactory = $quesModelFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customername');  
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('CUSTOM\Proques\Model\Ques');  
    $model->setCustomerName($name)
    $model->->save();
}
```

I DON'T WANT TO CALL MODEL LIKE THIS

> $this->_objectManager->create('CUSTOM\Proques\Model\Ques');

Is Any  way to call model without objectmanager in controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Factory, you have to append `Factory`to the class name:
`\CUSTOM\Proques\Model\QuesFactory $quesModelFactory`. This will be appended automatically.

You should use the factory to generate a single model:
`$ques = $this->quesModelFactory->create();`

After that, you can load the model with `$ques->load($quesId);`, set data with `$ques->setData('detail', $detail)` and save it with `$ques->save()`. 
Beware that this method is deprecated, so you should use the resource model instead, if you haven't  implemented a repository`.

Add a field and the dependency to the resource model:

```
private $quesResource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \CUSTOM\Proques\Model\QuesFactory $quesModelFactory,
    \CUSTOM\Proques\Model\ResourceModel\Ques $quesResource
) {
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->quesModelFactory = $quesModelFactory;
    $this->quesResource = $questResource
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Then you can load the model with `$this->quesResource->load($ques, $quesId);` and save it with `$this->quesResource->save($ques)`.

The whole code can look like this:

```
private $pageFactory;
private $quesModelFactory;
private $quesResource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \CUSTOM\Proques\Model\QuesFactory $quesModelFactory,
    \CUSTOM\Proques\Model\ResourceModel\Ques $quesResource
) {
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->quesModelFactory = $quesModelFactory;
    $this->quesResource = $questResource
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    //$datas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('detail');

    $ques = $this->quesModelFactory->create();
    $this->quesResource->load($ques, $quesId); 
    $ques->setData('detail', $detail);
    $this->quesResource->save($ques);
}
```

Unfortunately the question was changed after I started writing my answer. If you have an EAV model, there is a method `saveAttribute` in the resource model which you can use as follows:

```
    $ques = $this->quesModelFactory->create();
    $this->quesResource->load($ques, $quesId); 
    $ques->setData('detail', $detail);
    $this->quesResource->saveAttribute($ques, 'detail');
```

If you have a non-eav model, you will have to use the `save` functionality and save the complete model.